# How to keep view changes after refresh page?

Tags: javascript, html

In my MVC application i have a view in which i refresh the page each 10 seconds.
I have some paragraph in the view are hidden and a button which make those paragraphs not hidden.
The problem that when i click on the button to make the paragraph show when the page reload automatically in 10 seconds returns the paragraph  hidden.

This is the button:

```
 <button id="button">Display Internal Sequences</button>
```

This is the paragraph :

```
<p1 hidden style="text-align:center;font-size: 50px; padding:-25px; margin:-25px;">@Html.Label(@Model.CSLine.ModuleOrderInternalSequence > long.MinValue ? @Model.CSLine.ModuleOrderInternalSequence.ToString() : string.Empty)</p1>
```

This is the script to make the p not hidden:

```
   <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#button").click(function () {

             $("p1").attr("hidden", false);
              var show ='true';            
              localStorage.setItem(key, show);   

              });
          });
      </script>
```

This is the reload each 10 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload(1);
        }, 10000);
$(document).ready(function() {
    var show = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (show == 'true') 
    {
        $("p1").attr("hidden", false);
    }           })
```

The result is that the paragraph returns hidden after each reload.
I want when i click the button the paragraph  became not hidden even after reload.

Thank you

Comment: Is it becase you’re reloading the page before getting the localStorage? So that part of the script never runs?

Comment: you should show on document ready, not in the timeout - just let the timeout do the reload and then once the page has loaded, the document ready will kick in so you can check your local storage then and then set the visibility at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://jsfiddle.net/hbmk7e2L/

Note: Your page will only reload **after** 10 seconds in this case and will only refresh once.

If you want the page to refresh every 10 seconds, you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // If you want the page to refresh constantly, you should use setInterval intead of setTimeout. setTimeout fires only once.
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 10000);

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("p1").attr("hidden", false);
        localStorage.setItem("show_p1", true);
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem("show_p1") == 'true') {
        $("p1").attr("hidden", false);  
    }
  });
</script>


<p1 hidden style="text-align:center;font-size: 50px; padding:-25px; margin:-25px;">@Html.Label(@Model.CSLine.ModuleOrderInternalSequence > long.MinValue ? @Model.CSLine.ModuleOrderInternalSequence.ToString() : string.Empty)</p1>

<button id="button">Display Internal Sequences</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (show = 'true')
```

This is not a comparison, you are setting the value of "show" to "true". Use == to compare values.

Comment: @AmiraAbdouli When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved.

Comment: @AmiraAbdouli Also make sure that the variable "key" has some value.

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery's [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of `attr()` like so:

```
$("p1").prop("hidden", false);
```

The jQuery documentation for `prop()` describes the difference between the two methods, especially for boolean attributes like `hidden`. Also, here is a post regarding this [.prop() vs.attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)